# Unable to create to obtain OpenId Configuration

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect

I am using OpenIdConnect for Authentication with Azure AD. The application is hosted on IIS. I got below exception few days back:

**IDX10803**: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Stack Trace is:    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__3.MoveNext()

After 30 to 40 mins the application automatically started working normally. I just want to know the possible reasons for above exception. Is it a network issue or any specific reason. Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error says it was unable to get the config from: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

This is most likely a network issue, or a problem with Azure AD.
It could also happen if you used an invalid tenant id, but this is not the case here since you seem to have used "common" which is valid for multi-tenant apps.